# Incomputable sets of low degree vs Rices theorem?

Tags: turing-machines

I have heard that there are sets that are not computable, but are lower in degree than the halting problem.

How does this not contradict Rice's theorem? Are there any concrete examples of such sets?

Comment: And, as far as I remember, all examples of such sets are constructed for that single purpose, so I don't think you find any "concrete examples" of such sets.  (See _The Priority Method_.)

Comment: You should explain *why* you think there is a contradiction. We have too little information to be able to answer, unless you are willing to accept "Nope, there is no contradiction."

Comment: In trying to answer that, I realized why there is no contradiction: Rice's theorem is for predicates on Turing machines - our non-computable set that is lower than the halting set will not be a predicate on Turing machines.. it'll have to be something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but way too long to be a comment.  I just wanted to cite Robert I. Soare's *Recursively Enumerable Sets and Degrees*, Chapter V: *Simple Sets and Post's Problem*.

> **1: *Immune Sets, Simple Sets, and Post's Construction***
>
> The only r.e. degrees constructed so far are $\textbf{0}$ and
> $\textbf{0}'$.  *Post's Problem* was to construct other r.e. degrees,
> i.e., to construct an r.e. set $A$ such that
> $\emptyset \lt_\text{T} A \lt_\text{T} \emptyset'$.  *Post's Program*
> for constructing such a set $A$ was to ﬁnd some easily deﬁnable property
> on $\overline{A}$ (compatible with $A$ being nonrecursive) which
> guarantees incompleteness ($K \not\leq_\text{T} A$).
>
> Recall (from Theorem II.4.5) that $K$ (and hence any creative set) has
> an inﬁnite r.e. set (and therefore inﬁnitely many inﬁnite r.e. sets)
> contained in its complement. Post's idea for constructing $A$ incomplete
> was to make $\overline{A}$ sufﬁciently "thin" with respect to
> containment of inﬁnite r.e. sets so that $\overline{K}$ could not be
> Turing reduced to $\overline{A}$.
>
> **1.1 Deﬁnition.** (i) A set is *immune* if it is infinite but contains no
> infinite r.e. set.
> (ii) A set $A$ is *simple* if $A$ is r.e. and $\overline{A}$ is immune.
>
> **1.2 Proposition.** If $A$ is simple then:
>
> (i) $A$ is not recursive;
> (ii) $A$ is not creative;
> (iii) $A$ is not $m$-complete (i.e., $K \not\leq_m A$).
>
> Proof. (i) $\overline{A}$ cannot be r.e., since otherwise it contains an
> inﬁnite r.e. set (namely $\overline{A}$).
>
> (ii) The complement of a creative set does contain an inﬁnite r.e. set (by
> Theorem II.4.5).
>
> (iii) If $K \leq_m A$, then $A$ is creative (by Corollary II.4.8). $\Box$
>
> **1.3 Theorem** (Post [1944]). There exists a simple set $S$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $A = \{(e,x) \;:\; x \in W_e \;\&\; x > 2e \}$.  Now $A$ is
> $\Sigma_1$ and hence r.e. Let $\psi$ be any p.r. selector function for
> $A$ (in the sense of Theorem II.1.6) and let $S = \text{rng}\; \psi$.
> (Intuitively, enumerate $W_e$ until the ﬁrst element $\psi(e) > 2e$
> appears in $W_e$, and then put $\psi(e)$ into $S$.) The following facts
> give the simplicity of $S$.
>
> (1) $S$ is r.e. ($S$ is the range or a p.r. function.)
>
> (2) $\overline{S}$ is inﬁnite.  To see this, note that $S$ contains at
> most $e$ elements out of $\{0,1,2,\dots,2e\}$, namely $\psi(0),\psi(1), \dots, \psi(e-1)$. Hence $e + 1 \leq \text{card}(\overline{S} \upharpoonright (2e+1))$, so $\overline{S}$ is inﬁnite.
>
> (3) If $W_e$, is inﬁnite, then $W_e \cap S \neq \emptyset$, because
> $(e,x) \in A$ for some $x > 2e$ and so $\psi(e)$ is deﬁned and $\psi(e) \in S \cap W_e$. $\Box$